# Proof of Focal length of a Hyperbola

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I have recently learned about the Hyperbolas and it's properties. The formula for finding the *focal length* that is $$f^2 = a^2 + b^2$$, where *f*, *a*, and *b* is the *focal length*, distance from center to *vertices*, and distance from center to the *co-vertices*, respectively, is confusing to me that from where does this formula came from? and how is it derived? I want to know the proof of it. I searched in different books and even tried myself but I was unable to prove.

Focal length: the distance from the center to the focus of the hyperbola.
Co-vertex: The endpoints of the conjugate axis of the hyperbola.

My brain is a kind of skeptical, it just doesn't accept things the way they are, so please help me.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What are your definitions of *focal length*, *vertices* and *co-vertices*? Have you tried to derive this formula from these definitions? Please include such information to allow others here to answer your question appropriately.

Comment: I think anyone who studied about the hyperbola, would know these terminologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that the focal lenght is the ditance of the foci from the origin. So we draw a circunference with centre $O(0,0)$ and radius $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

[image]

From the graph, it easy to see that the radius of the circle is also the focal lenght and so:
$$f^2=a^2+b^2$$

Comment: Thank you so much!
I got it,

Comment: Thank you so much!

I got it, actually, the $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$ is the distance between the vertex and the co-vertex which is equal to the focal length and by drawing a circle we can clearly see that.

Thanks, now I can appreciate more about the hyperbolas.

Comment: I really really want to but I don't have a reputation of at least 15 :((